# How to design an icon in Snack bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, snackbar, android-snackbar

Is there any way to put a button on Snack bar to do some actions like canceling , undo or closing the snack bar with clicking on a designed icon?
i'm usin Kotlin and Xml in android studio

tried using actions but i want an icon to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

### [Adding an action](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md#adding-an-action)

To add an action, use the `setAction` method on the object returned from make. Snackbars are automatically dismissed when the action is clicked.

To show a snackbar with a message and an action:

```
Snackbar.make(contextView, R.string.text_label, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction(R.string.action_text) {
        // Responds to click on the action
    }
    .show()
```